# Why does the function require_once prevent my code from working

Tags: php, pdo, connection, require-once

At the top of my code I have the following

```
require_once 'PSBE_LOGIN';
```

where PSBE_LOGIN has all the information to access my database(I'm using a PDO connection). However, my code does not work but when I take it out, my code works perfectly. Any thoughts on why this is? I need the file there so I can collect information from my database.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this string?

Comment: And what exactly is PSBE_LOGIN? A file?

Comment: I assume its a constant, try it without the quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Require` (as opposed to `include`) will halt the execution of a script on failure. For example, if the specified file is not found.

Thus your code *can* be fixed by ensuring the file exists and in the correct directory.

Answer (score 0):

Hi try this ( no quotes )

```
require_once PSBE_LOGIN;
```